# How to convert Documents read from Mongo Collection using MongoDbIO.read() directly to a table row without explicity mentioning each and every key?

Tags: java, mongodb, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

```
Read read= MongoDbIO.read().withUri(<uri>).withBucketAuto(true)
            .withDatabase(<db>).withCollection(<collection>);

PCollection<Document> lines = p.apply(read);
```

How to convert `lines` to `tablerows` dynamically *without* fetching each line and setting the table row like this:

```
String offer_id=document.getString("oid");
TableRow row;
row=new TableRow().set("offerId", offer_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible now since anyway `MongodbIO.Read` will return a `PCollection<Document>` that has to be converted into `PCollection<TableRow>`.

However, if you need it to write the result of `MongodbIO.Read` into BigQuery then I think you may try to use `BigQueryIO.Write.withFormatFunction(...)` and provide a function to convert MongoDB document into `TableRow`. Though, I think it will be kind of the same in terms of performance.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. So I have to individually select each and every key value ? I cannot map it to a property name(column name) directly?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no build-in map function like this. So, you need to create your own and provide it to BigQueryIO.Write.withFormatFunction(...)